# Can Dynamic Data website concept of ASP .Net used in Enterprise level application

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are 3 Options available in front of me for architecting application

1. Formview / Gridview & LINQDataSource
2. Dynamic Data Website
3. Classic Design (Using Textbox & other controls, writing code to get and set data from entity classes)

Please guide me ...what option i should use and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three are potentially viable but since we don't know much about your "enterprise level" requirements it's not the easiest to say if one is better than the other.

Looking at your three options I would say all three could even be used together.  For example, you could use Dynamic Data for maintaining back end tables such as lookup values.  Item #1 and #3 are fairly close in my opinion as formview & gridview are just controls and entity classes / linq data sources could be used together / in conjunction with each other also.